Tilting floor in cave or dungeon (movie from the 90s or maybe early 2000s)
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie.
These are the points I remember:

The characters are in a cave or dungeon.
They do something that results in the floor becoming unbalanced. They almost fall into a chasm,
And they manage to balance themselves and escape.
The movie may be from the 90s or maybe early 2000s
It's an American made movie.
It was action & adventure.
Might have been on the funny side (like Golden Child or Jumanji)
It was not an animated movie.


Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification.  What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I feel like I know the one you mean, though I can't think of its name.  The floor-balancing trap was all made of stone, and supposed to be ancient.  I'm leaning strongly towards National Treasure: Book of Secrets.

Is this it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDxiflW57r4 at 1:45

I think it might be National Treasure: The Book of Secrets
Released in 2007.  Features scenes in a cave/dungeon.
Has a floor that needs balancing.  You can see the floor in the trailer at 1:45:



American, has some humour, and so forth.
Here's a pic of the tilting floor:


Nice, you rock Tim. That's the movie I was thinking about. Thanks for your help!!

@Scott No problems.  Feel free to tick the acceptance button (under the voting flags).
